# Why is the sticky position in my CSS not working?

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I'm trying to get a sidebar to stick on scroll but it's not working. How can I figure out the missing step of incorrect code? The sidebar should float in the same position of the view-port. Here's the code I'm using:

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.sidebar-nav-list {
  padding: 0 .625rem 1.25rem 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 2.625rem;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 2px solid #1a73e8
}

.sidebar-nav-list a {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e52207;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-list">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-list">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-list">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check everywhere weather you are defining overflow property in css if yes then remove it , use top:0 remove px at end , if still doesn't work i always go with position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

You will need additional styles to align properly, but this should get the sidebar fixed to the left.

```
.sidebar-nav {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Eric.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there. In your question I see you want to position the menu to the **viewport**. In that case you can **use** for example **`position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;`**. Why? I will try to explain below, since the 'why' is the most important part when solving problems!

**Position 'fixed'**

**`position: fixed;`** the element is removed from the document flow and is relative to its containing block established **by the viewport**. **Except** when one of its **ancestors** has a **transform, perspective, or filter** property added (other then none). In that case it is relative to that ancestor.

**Position 'sticky'**

**`position: sticky;`** is **relative to** it's nearest scrolling **ancestor**. So if your nearest scrolling ancestor is not the height of your viewport (or bigger), but the same size as your element that is 'sticky' it won't 'stick.'  ;)

A few examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

More in-depths information about position sticky and fixed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you for your insight.